# How to negate `is:` filter property in Chrome DevTools network panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

As documented on [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#filter-by-property) it is possible to filter using the `is:` property. For example, `is:service-worker-intercepted` will show all network requests which are intercepted by the service-worker. Is it possible to filter for the inverse of this property, i.e. to negate the results (for example `is:!service-worker-intercepted` would show all requests which were not intercepted by the service-worker)?

Answer (score 1):

I Have not found a opposite of `is:` but for that particular property `is:service-worker-initiated` does what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can negate your query by prefixing it with a dash, e.g.: `-is:service-worker-initiated`.